# Which are the possible reasons for my app's memory usage being so high?

Tags: android, performance, memory, memory-management

I am currently writing an app and I'm using mostly one activity. [This is the component tree.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RrKtu.png)

I'm using two screen width and about 300px high images in the upper two image views, the lowest one is a solid colored panel. In addition to this, the app also creates about 15 buttons with vector backgrounds and a size of about square 42dp. Those buttons do not possess a click listener and I've turned off the stateListAnimator for them. They do not function as proper buttons but replacing them with a textView, for example, has not remedied the problem.

I also load 48 sound files into a SoundPool, with an individual size of 8,57 KB per file. I tried not loading these files, but that did not change the RAM usage in any significant fashion.

I have minifyEnabled set to true and those are my dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc02'
    implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:28.0.0-rc02'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0-rc02'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0-rc02'
    implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0-rc02'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:preference-v7:28.0.0-rc02'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

My problem now is that this app, while it does not seem to possess any leaks, uses up a lot of RAM right from the start. It differs from device to device, but it's usually between 70mb and 130mb. [Here is a shot of the Android profiler.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K9hIG.png)

Not using ads has a slight effect, but nothing too wild, as seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j1Nuq.png).

So at this point I am not entirely sure what could be causing the problem and which steps I can take to figure this out. So I hope anybody here can help.

If any additional information that I forgot about is required, I will provide it. Thanks.

Comment: Check your drawable/mipmap directory maybe you're using some big images that needs a lot of memory to be loaded. Also if you're using a background image check that too(remove it and test). Otherwise give "Leakcanary" a try to look for any memory leaks

Comment: The entirety of my "drawable" folders has a total size of about 200 KB, so I kinda doubt it. And again, the app doesn't seem to be leaking memory. I've left it to run for an hour and used it for half an hour and it stayed pretty consistent.

Answer (score 0):

check the size of your images maybe one of them has a big size
and try to optimize your xml code it could be the reason why your app uses a lot of RAM.
and check  "LeakCanary" it helps a lot when it came to RAM